# Python destroying content to save memory

Tags: python

I have a class to get a webpage's html and do some things with it

```
import requests

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.r = requests.get(url)
        self.html = self.r.text
        #other things

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,url):
        super(B,self).__init__(url)
        #other things
```

I am going to instantiate this class hundreds of thousands of times, like so

```
for url in many_urls:
    page = B(url)
    #other things
```

how can I make sure that the content like `page.html` and other attributes get deleted and aren't kept in memory to slow it down?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this blog post](http://tech.oyster.com/save-ram-with-python-slots/). Since you're defining your own classes, you may be able to use \_\_slots\_\_ to save some memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html will be held in memory for as long as the object that references it exists.

If your `for` loop does not assign the `B` object to any other variable, then each time you re-assign `page` the previously created `B` object will become eligible for garbage collection, and the html will be removed from memory at the same time.

If you are retaining references to each of your `B` objects you will slowly fill up your memory, but if you allow them to be garbage collected you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `del page` or `page = None`, both statements release the content for garbage collection. This makes sense if your for-loop kernel is memory critical or you are using object that bring their own memory management (like numpy.ndarray).

Also note that variables "bleed" out of the scope of for-loops. That means that the `page` from the last iteration will be present until the current scope is terminated (usually at the end of the function/method).

Comment: Keep in mind that `del page` might not release the memory, if there are other references to `page`.

Comment: @NedBatchelder That is expected behaviour with the reference counting that python does. Without knowing what the `#other things` done to `page` are, we cannot say this will actually free the memory. Being vocal about your intentions with `del` has certainly no downside.